# Last element during multiplication of sparse matrice not printing?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have just started data structures and I was practicing multiplication of sparse matrice via triplet representation. My code was:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
  int smatrix1[4][3]={{1,2,10},{1,3,12},{2,1,1},{2,3,2}};
  int smatrix2[4][3]={{1,1,2},{1,3,8},{2,1,5},{2,2,1}};
  int i,j,x=0;
  int smatrix3[4][4];
  for(int i=0;i<4;){
    int r=smatrix1[i][0];
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
      int c=smatrix2[j][0];
      int tempa=i,tempb=j;
      int sum=0;
      while(tempa<=4 && smatrix1[tempa][0]==r && tempb<=4 && smatrix2[tempb][0]==c){
        if(smatrix1[tempa][1]<smatrix2[tempb][1])
          tempa++;
        else if(smatrix1[tempa][1]>smatrix2[tempb][1])
          tempb++;
        else if(smatrix1[tempa][1]==smatrix2[tempb][1])
          sum+=smatrix1[tempa++][2]*smatrix2[tempb++][2];
        printf("%d\n",sum);
      }
      printf("R C SUM %d%d%d\n",r,c,sum);
      if(sum!=0){
        smatrix3[x][0]=r;
        smatrix3[x][1]=c;
        smatrix3[x][2]=sum;
        x++;
      }
      while(j<=4 && smatrix2[j][0]==c)
        j++;
    }
    while(i<=4 && smatrix1[i][0]==r)
      i++;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",smatrix3[i][0],smatrix3[i][1],smatrix3[i][2]);
  }
}
```

While all the elements are printing correctly, the last element results in garbage value. I tried to dry run it but same result. Can anyone please tell me the reason as well as solution?
Edit: I added <=4 instead of <4 incase last element was ignored due to postscript ++ operator. Adding or removing = sign had no effect whatsoever.

Comment: A very quick look at your code seems to have it referencing smatrix1[tempa] where tempa can be 4.  That would be beyond the bounds of the array so all behaviour is undefined.

Comment: yes, originally it was <4 instead of <=4 but still the result was same. I changed incase the loop was ignoring last element due to post script ++ operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Here's your problem.  This line should not being incrementing j:

Change:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
```

To:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;){
```

Also all the comparisons for '<= 4' should be '< 4'

Comment: But it shouldn't be. Because when i=2 and j=2,then there if a case where smatrix1[tempa][1] is equal to smatrix2[tempb][1] i.e {2,1,1} and {2,1,5}. So the output should 2 2 5 in place of 0 which is shown in program

Comment: I've looked at your implementation which seems to be a derivative of this one:
 
http://coding-c.blogspot.com/2010/12/program-for-multiplication-of-2-sparse.html

And the difference seems to be when printing

 for(int i=0;i<x;i++){  // Change 4 to x

Comment: I did as you asked. What it does is that it simply omits the last value i.e 2 2 5

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort sir